# Fill HTML form via TWebBrowser in Delphi on Android

Tags: android, forms, delphi, twebbrowser

On a website's `<form>` I want to set the text of an `<input>` and submit that form using `TWebBrowser`. I want this for Delphi on Android similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28955227/19510606), but that only works on Windows.

Comment: The code you linked to won't work on Android because it's for Windows. You should be able to use the ExecuteJavascript method to use Javascript commands to fill out the relevant fields, such as this Javascript: `document.getElementById("nameofid").value = "My value";`. If you have problems working that out, update your question with the code you have tried

Comment: I would be grateful if you could help me send and submit a string to the field in twebbrowser in Delphi Android.

Comment: There's already an important [comment to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944006/delphi-twebbrowser-identify-html-element-id/28955227#comment46142144_28944006) of your linked answer: why requesting the website thru [HTTP GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) to begin with if you could submit all needed data with a [HTTP POST request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP))? And please don't use comments to just repeat what's in your question already.

Comment: Thanks
But when I use the code you said I get this error... I am using Delphi 11.1 for Android
Error:
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(81): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'IHTMLDocument2'
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(82): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'IHTMLFormElement'
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(84): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'IHTMLElementCollection'

Answer (score 0):

The code you linked to works only on Windows, because it use VCL Webbrowser component that depends on Microsoft IE ActiveX and its engine (MSHTML) on which that code rely (by using components and interfaces such as IHTMLElementCollection).

For a cross-platform solution, if you are using FMX Webbrowser component or other third-party cross-platform webbrowser for Delphi, you can use its function for executing JavaScript ("EvaluateJavaScript" for FMX Webbrowser, or "ExecuteJavascript" if you are using TMSFNCWebBrowser from TMS Software) for the aim of editing and filling and even submitting the HTML form through JavaScript DOM codes.

It is an excellent cross-platform solution, you have to formulate a JavaScript code snippet and put it in the "EvaluateJavaScript", pay attention to the delimiters and the length of your string, like the following code for filling the field (with id "username") with the value "foo" and submitting the form (with id "myform") :

```
procedure FillForm;
begin
Webbrowser1.EvaluateJavaScript('document.getElementById(''username'').value="foo";' + 'document.getElementById(''myform'').submit();');
end;
```

Otherwise, if you are the developer of the website containing that form or you know how it is processed (action page, request type and parameters names), then you can simply send data through REST requests. Just use the REST Client Library and formulate a request to the action page then you implement the code for handling the received response.